# How to backup and restore docker containers (without the original docker run command)

Tags: json, docker, runc

I want to be able to "freeze" a container state into a file and then restore it later if the container is accidentally deleted. This is to prevent accidental container deletion.

I tried `docker export` to a tar file, then `docker import`, but it will create an *image* of the docker filesystem... not the container itself. I know that I can use `docker run` from this image but I am not the container creator and I don't know what command was used to create it originally.

I also tried to use `docker-runc` to recreate the container from its `rootfs` and `config.json` from `/run/docker/libcontainerd/CONTAINER_ID/config.json`, but I see that this will not be easy and I wanted a "not so hack-ish" solution.

Currently, the only way I know to achieve this is to create snapshots of the docker host VM and, if someone accidentally deletes a container, restore the snapshot. But the last time this happened, the last backup was taken 16 hours before, and I lost all data created after that (and the recovery process too a good amount of time).

I just wanted to save the container state into a file and be able to recreate it in case of deletion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [docker autocompose](https://github.com/Red5d/docker-autocompose) to get a `docker-compose.yml` equivalent that will allow you to recreate the container together with the image you saved.

Comment: Yes, this would solve my problem. Unfortunately I got an error for the docker-compose file generated by the tool:  `# docker-compose -f /tmp/backup_c1 up -d
Creating c1 ... 
Creating c1 ... error

ERROR: for c1  Cannot start service c1: b'oci runtime error: container_linux.go:262: starting container process caused "exec: \\"nginx -g daemon off;\\": executable file not found in $PATH"'`

Comment: That might be related to incompatibilities between the file generated (file version 1) and the docker engine/compose. What about just doing a `docker commit`? That should keep environment variables, exposed ports, etc.

Comment: `docker commit` will also create an image - not a container

Comment: I have found the error on docker-autocompose and will send a PR to fix it.